# Can I encrypt data transferring between my app and DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, networking, heroku

I need to connect from Heroku to a remote DB, How can I make this connection be encrypted.

Comment: I need to do this with postgres or mysql, and mongoDB

Answer (score 3):

How to do this depends on the type of database.

With MySQL, you can use [SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ssl-connections.html) to secure the connection.

With PostgreSQL you can use [SSH Tunnels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssh-tunnels.html).

Comment: Thank you! But I don't think SSH Tunneling is available on Heroku.